# How do I achieve desktop overlay blur on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, effects, dwm

When I was installing AMD graphics drivers on Windows 10, I noticed a blurred background look, which is a style I want to achieve in my application.

[image: AMD Radeon Installer]

I have tried using [UpdateLayeredWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx), but it does not apply a blur effect. I have tried using [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512.aspx) and [DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969508(v=vs.85).aspx) but I am unsure how to customize window coloring 
and image overlays.

There is a [DwmGetColorizationColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969513(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but there is no matching DwmSetColorizationColor function. There are ways to set system-wide coloring, but I would like colorization to affect solely my application window. Also, Aero Glass™ was removed from Windows 8 and 10.

How do I include these effects in my application using WinForms in a way that works on Windows 8/10? If WPF can render these effects, how does it do it and how do I achieve a similar effect on WinForms?

Comment: Which technology do you use for the application? Forms? UWP? WPF?

Comment: I'm forced to use WinForms.

Comment: Or try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386452/blurring-the-background-of-a-semi-transparent-form-like-aero-glass

Comment: What system function calls does WPF make to achieve that effect?

Comment: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Vista-Glass-In-C.aspx

Comment: On Windows Vista and 7, Aero Glass works as intended. Unfortunately, that feature was removed from Windows 8 and 10. The installer UI screenshot is taken on Windows 10, hence one can safely conclude that it *is not* using Dwm Aero Glass functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After months of searching, I have finally found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724187/how-do-you-set-the-glass-blend-colour-on-windows-10). To achieve the glass effect on Windows 10, one must use the undocumented [SetWindowCompositionAttribute](http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/user32.dll/SetWindowCompositionAttribute.php) function in `user32.dll`.

[image: Windows 10 Aero Glass Demonstration]

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowCompositionAttribute(HWND hwnd, WINCOMPATTRDATA* pAttrData)
```

where the layout of the `WINCOMPATTRDATA` structure is:

```
struct WINCOMPATTRDATA {
    DWORD attribute; // the attribute to query, see below
    PVOID pData; //buffer to store the result
    ULONG dataSize; //size of the pData buffer
};
```

and `attribute` can have values from the [DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute) enum.