# How to achieve the Adobe XD background blur effect in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, blur, effect

So, I need to apply a blur effect to a button that is inside a window with image background. If I try to add it to the button, the effect blurs only the content of the button, but not the window background.

I want to achieve the Adobe XD "background blur" effect:

[image: 1]

How can I do? Thanks!!

Comment: No, the BitmapEffect applied to the background image blur the entire background, while I want to blur only the button.

Comment: If your button position is fixed, you can the same image on as a background of the block and one blurred for the button

Comment: The background image will be dynamic. I can't create a new one every time.

Comment: Possibly related: [Apply blur to everything behind a chosen container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570639/apply-blur-to-everything-behind-a-chosen-container), [WPF: Blur wpf content behind a usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098139/wpf-blur-wpf-content-behind-a-usercontrol)

Comment: Do i need Photoshop for this? I also do not know the HLSL.

Comment: If i apply the blur to an element under the button it don't blur the background but only that element.

Comment: I found a solution: I set the button background to a VisualBrush that link to the blur image, behind the background image. Now i need to fit that VisualBrush to the entire window. How can I do?